# How do i set 100% in a div tag background?

Tags: css

I am trying to tell my CSS code that, if the browser is resized then resize the logo size also.

So here is what I have done:

```
 #logo {
background:url('../images/logo.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    max-width:423px;
    max-height:99px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

I would be grateful if someone could tell me how to fix this problem? I don't understand what i am doing wrong.

In my HTML i have this: `<div id="logo"></div>`

The logo is not displaying unless i take away `width:100%; height:100%`, i must replace it with the exact size in pixels.

Edit: I am trying to shrink the logo when the browser is resized to a smaller size, hope this makes it more clear however, it does not display right now.

Thanks.

Comment: for the 100% to work on the div, you also have to give html and body 100% width & height, because this div has no parent with fixed size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place an absolute `img` tag to be the background of the div with `max-width` & `max-height` applyed in percentage. that way, when you resize the page, the div shrinks and cause the `img` to shrink.

see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/j5Kwr/2/

Comment: I think so. you can wait for other answers, maybe their is another solution.

Answer (score 2):

You have a max-width and a max-height. Obviously, if the logo's 100% of each is higher than the amount you set, it will not grow any more.

Comment: Yes, that is right. What i want it to do is shrink and at the same time it doesn't display.

Comment: Please re-explain your exact problem, I don't quite understand it.

Answer (score 1):

You probably can play with

`background-size: contain;`

Try to resize Result fame *(make it very small width)* here http://jsfiddle.net/f6F86/

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is set width:423px; and height:99px; and for max-width:100%;

Answer (score 0):

You can try placing the image directly in your HTML markup. This makes the requirement of a set width and height redundant.

CSS

```
#logo {
        max-width:423px;
        max-height:99px;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        display:inline-block;
    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="logo">
   <img src="link_to_image_here" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#logo {
    background:url('../images/logo.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    max-width:423px;
    height: 99px;
    max-height:99px;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-position: 0 0;
    display:inline-block;
}
```